# Reading peerinvalid Output

Tags: npm, npm-install

Taking the following output from a vanilla `npm install`:

```
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package grunt does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-tslint@2.5.0 wants grunt@~0.4.5
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-processhtml@0.3.13 wants grunt@>=0.4.x
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-copy@0.8.2 wants grunt@>=0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-bower-install@1.6.0 wants grunt@~0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-connect@0.11.2 wants grunt@>=0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-watch@0.4.0 wants grunt@~0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-lesslint@1.4.1 wants grunt@~0.4.5
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-typescript@0.8.0 wants grunt@~0.4.5
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-bower-concat@0.6.0 wants grunt@~0.4.0
```

How does one diagnose the dependency version problems from package.json, which has the following dependencies:

```
"grunt": "0.4.5",
"grunt-bower-concat": "^0.6.0",
"grunt-bower-install": "^1.6.0",
"grunt-bower-task": "^0.4.0",
"grunt-contrib-connect": "0.11.2",
"grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.8.2",
"grunt-contrib-less": "^1.0.1",
"grunt-contrib-watch": "0.4.0",
"grunt-processhtml": "^0.3.8",
"grunt-lesslint": "^1.4.0",
"grunt-tslint": "^2.4.0",
"grunt-typescript": "^0.8.0",
"matchdep": "~0.1.1",
"tslint": "^2.4.2"
```

The peerDependencies have the following distinct rules:

```
~0.4.5   :: True, grunt dependency is hard-coded as exactly 0.4.5
>=0.4.x  :: True, 0.4.5 >= 0.4.x
>=0.4.0  :: True, 0.4.5 >= 0.4.0
~0.4.0   :: True, 0.4.5 is a patch of 0.4.0
```

All of these pass for the stated version of the `grunt` dependency. Why does NPM still complain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `npm install` is executed it will assess the compatibility of the **packages that are currently installed**.

Starting from a blank `node_modules` directory, a `package.json` with the dependencies described above will install successfully.

The root cause of this issue is manually installing a later version of grunt:

```
# First NPM install, works sucecssfully
npm install

# Upgrade to later version of grunt, note we're not adding --save
npm install grunt@1.0.0

# NPM install now fails with incompatibility error
npm install
```

In this case, the `package.json` file still shows grunt at version `0.4.5`, but the installed module is still `1.0.0`.

To find a list of the installed modules, one should consult `npm list`